# How to add Scheduled notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I have been trying to add a scheduled notification feature to my todo app but am unable to do so, when the notification is supposed to appear, it does not and the app crashes, I want the notification to be added when the add button in the todoScreen is clicked.
any help would be really appreciated.

todoScreen link: https://github.com/Rohith-JN/Reminders_App/blob/main/lib/Screens/TodoScreen.dart

notification link: https://github.com/Rohith-JN/Reminders_App/blob/main/lib/notification_service.dart

Comment: Are you converting schedule to tz format?

Comment: Yes did you look at the code?

Comment: does it throw any error or something in the console when crashes?

Comment: It does not throw an exception or anything but in the debug console it shows: E/AndroidRuntime( 5314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5314): Process: com.example.todo_app, PID: 5314
E/AndroidRuntime( 5314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay pushing notification with flutter is pretty easy.
Add these **dependencies** to **pubspec.yaml**:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.2
  rxdart: ^0.23.1
```

Particular plugins: [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart)

then run this command in the terminal:

```
flutter pub get
```

Go to ***AndroidManifest.xml*** in `/android/app/src/main/` and add these lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Now, go to ***AppDelegate.swift*** in `/ios/Runner/` Add:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as ? 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate    
}
```

before these lines:

```
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

**Done?**

Now, Create a `notifications_helper.dart` file and import the `flutter_local_notifications` and `rxdart packages`.
Then in that file add these:

```
class NotificationClass{
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
  final String payload;
NotificationClass({this.id, this.body, this.payload, this.title});
}
```

Also add these `finals`:

```
final rxSub.BehaviorSubject<NotificationClass> didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject =
    rxSub.BehaviorSubject<NotificationClass>();
final rxSub.BehaviorSubject<String> selectNotificationSubject =
    rxSub.BehaviorSubject<String>();
```

Now finally add the following `method` to helper file:

```
Future<void> initNotifications(
    notifs.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        notifsPlugin) async {
  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
      notifs.AndroidInitializationSettings('icon');
  var initializationSettingsIOS = notifs.IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
        didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject
            .add(NotificationClass(id: id, title: title, body: body, payload: payload));
      });
  var initializationSettings = notifs.InitializationSettings(
      initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
  await notifsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      print('notification payload: ' + payload);
    }
    selectNotificationSubject.add(payload);
  });
  print("Notifications initialised successfully");
}
```

For permission request method for iOS:

```
void requestIOSPermissions(
    notifs.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifsPlugin) {
  notifsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<notifs.IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.requestPermissions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
}
```

**Done Up To This?**

Now, scheduled notification, add these:

```
Future<void> scheduleNotification(
    {notifs.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifsPlugin,
    String id,
    String title,
    String body,
    DateTime scheduledTime}) async {
  var androidSpecifics = notifs.AndroidNotificationDetails(
    id, // This specifies the ID of the Notification
    'Scheduled notification', // This specifies the name of the notification channel
    'A scheduled notification', //This specifies the description of the channel
    icon: 'icon',
  );
  var iOSSpecifics = notifs.IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platformChannelSpecifics = notifs.NotificationDetails(
      androidSpecifics, iOSSpecifics);
  await notifsPlugin.schedule(0, title, "Scheduled notification",
      scheduledTime, platformChannelSpecifics); // This literally schedules the notification
}
```

Now modify the `main.dart` file:

```
NotificationAppLaunchDetails notifLaunch;
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifsPlugin=    
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
```

Now within the main method, add

```
notifLaunch = await notifsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
await initNotifications(notifsPlugin);
requestIOSPermissions(notifsPlugin);
```

NOW MAIN THING,
Triggering a scheduled Notification, Import your `helper file` and `main.dart`:

```
import '../helpers/notifications_helper.dart';
import '../main.dart';
```

Now call the scheduleNotification method:

```
scheduleNotification(
    notifsPlugin: notifsPlugin, //Or whatever you've named it in main.dart
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    body: "A scheduled Notification",
    scheduledTime: DateTime.now()); //Or whenever you actually want to trigger it
```

And My friend you are done!

Comment: I tried this but the notification doesn't appear

Comment: Did you check all the method names correctly? Try updating the widgets and flutter version. Use the latest version of widgets. Also read the documentation of the widgets, maybe some ways are changed.

Comment: I decided to use another notification plugin called awesome_notifications and its working fine but not sure how to uniquely send a notification for each todo